# Newbie to makefiles. Want to understand some flags

Tags: gcc, makefile, ld

I wanted to know what these flags mean in a makefile

```
-rpath
-soname
-cvq
-MD
2> and some code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not at all related to `make` but rather to `gcc`/`ld`.

`make` is a meta-language, that allows you to automate build-processes.
so most things you find within a makefile, usually refer to how you call compilers and linkers and other programs needed to build an application (or a library, or something else).

check the manpages (`man gcc` and `man ld`) to get information about specific flags for a given program.

e.g.

- `-rpath DIR`: add DIR to runtime search path (ld)
- `-soname FILENAME`: set shared library name (ld)
- `-cvq`: i have no idea to program which these flags refer; most likely these are three flags `-c -v -q`, but who knows?
- `-MD`: usually used to generate include-dependencies from a .c file (gcc)
- `2>`: this is no flag at all, but redirects stderr to somewhere else (e.g. to a file)

Comment: I saw the -cvq flag in a command which links static libraries (the .a files) http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Answer (score 1):

The -cvq is combined by three flags:

-c: Whenever an archive is created, an informational message to that effect is written to standard error.

If the -c option is specified, ar creates the archive silently.

-v: Provide verbose output.

-q: Quickly append the specified files to the archive. If the archive does not exist a new archive file is created.

See more info here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/buildlib.html